# What is the first meaning of たたき台?

Tags: words

たたき台 means a springboard for discussion.

According to my dictionary, this word's first meaning is "chopping block".

On [Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%E3%81%9F%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8D%E5%8F%B0), it does not look like the plastic/wood board I use to cut meat/vegetables:

[image]

So what is the non-abstract meaning of たたき台?
[ALC does not have it](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%9F%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8D%E5%8F%B0).

Comment: Seems like something they'd use to chop/mash their vegetables and such on. Probably some old device from back when they didn't eat much meat. Not sure what you're asking but たたき seems like the verb stem for たたく, maybe that explains it?

Comment: That's interesting...When I read "chopping block" I think of a piece of wood used for chopping off necks (humans' *or* chickens'), not chopping up veggies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of meanings related to たたき台 (as noted by the comments and posts above.)

In one case (from your picture posted above,) たたき台 actually means something like **"a pounding stand"** for baseball gloves.  (Along with a たたき台, there is also another tool used when pounding baseball gloves like this, called a たたき棒; the actual glove-hitting tool.)

When you buy a typical baseball glove, it is usually made out of some sort of leather.  Leather usually requires some sort of maintenance from time to time (and especially before a glove, in this case, is first used.)

One type of glove maintenance is the art of *"creating a pocket"* so that a baseball fielder can more-easily catch a fly-ball... or field a ground ball... during a game of baseball.

The following (commercial) website describes what the process of *"creating a pocket" can* look like:
http://bba.co.jp/kakou-teire_shinka.html   ***(see step 7)***

Comment: Very interesting! I had no idea baseball gloves needed pounding. Most of the images on Google Images are definitely this tool.

Answer (score 2):

A tatakidai is quite literally a raised platform (台) that is hit / beat (叩く). Usually it is used by retailers who beat it in an attempt to attract customers while they shout out gradually reducing prices. Hence there is a sense of sale associated with it.

Comment: While I am confident in my answer as one non-abstract meaning, I do not think that it really answers your question when considering the image you gave. So I briefly Googled it. Apparently it is a グラブたたき台 and is used in baseball. I am not familiar with this usage nor really understand how it should be used. I will let someone else fill in the details.